# simplicial homology definition

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition

I am revising for my algebraic topology exam based on Hatchers 2nd chapter of algebraic topology and I have this question regarding the definition of simplicial homology on pages 104-105:

Hatcher defines $\Delta_n(X)$ to be the free abelian group with basis the open n simplices ${e_\alpha}^n$ of X where elements are the n-chains in the form $\sum_\alpha n_\alpha {e_\alpha}^n$ where $n_\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hatcher then goes on to say that this is equivalent to $\sum_\alpha n_\alpha \sigma_\alpha $ where **$\sigma_\alpha:\Delta^n \longrightarrow X$ is the characteristic map of ${e_\alpha}^n$.**

What is the characteristic map in this definition and how does it fit into the context of $\Delta$-Complexes? the only character i have seen in other modules is that of characters for representations but am unsure if this is relevant.

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: the simplex $\Delta^n$ lives in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ so when he says $e_{\alpha}^n$ is an $n$-simplex of $X$ this is really the canonical map $\sigma_\alpha: \Delta^{n}\to X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in Section 2.1 of Hatcher's book, a $\Delta$-complex structure on a space $X$ **is** a collection of maps $\sigma_\alpha : \Delta^n \to X$, satisfying a list of properties.

About a page after the beginning of that definition, Hatcher gives the notation $e^n_\alpha = \sigma_\alpha(\text{interior}(\Delta^n))$, and the terminology that $\sigma_\alpha$ is the characteristic map of the open cell $e^n_\alpha$. (He writes a little circle atop $\Delta^n$ instead of $\text{interior}(\Delta^n)$ but I do not know how to reproduce that here.)

Comment: '\mathring\Delta' gives $\mathring\Delta$

Comment: Ah! Thanks @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez